# Include date, IP and HTTP_HOST in Support form

Tags: php

I am trying to include the current date, senders IP and Host in my contact form submission.

This is the code:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['name']) )
{

$to = 'info@mydomain.com'; // Replace with your email   
$subject = 'Contact Form Submission'; // Replace with your $subject
$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' .         $_POST['email'];    

$date       = date('M jS, Y @ h:i a');
$IP     = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$Host       = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
           'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" .
           'Subject: ' . $_POST['subject'] . "\n" .
           'Department: ' . $_POST['department'] . "\n" .
           'Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . "\n" .
           'Date:  ' . $_POST['$date'] . "\n" .
           'IP:  ' . $_POST['$IP'] . "\n" .
           'Host:  ' . $_POST['$Host'];




mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);    
if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
{
    mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
}
}
?>
```

The Email is received, but without Date, IP and Host. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be aware of header injection. Since you're pasting `$_POST['email']` raw inside of the headers, it would be easy for anyone to use your service to send spam (by adding a billion BCC headers) and you'd probably have your email service ban you.

Comment: @h2ooooooo, i have modified my code as follows, however now the form is not sent:

<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   echo "<h1>Error</h1>\n
      <p>Accessing this page directly is not allowed.</p>";
   exit;
}

$email = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", $email);

$find = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:)/i";
if (preg_match($find, 'name') || preg_match($find, 'email') || preg_match($find, 'subject') || preg_match($find, 'message') || preg_match($find, 'department')) {
   echo "<h1>Error</h1>\n
      <p>No meta/header injections, please.</p>";
   exit;
}

if( isset($_POST['name']) )
{

 rest ...
?>

Comment: I would check your header array to see if there's anything in there that looks out of the ordinary. (`print_r`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already stored(ip, date etc.) in variables so use these variables for mail. also **these values are not exists in POST data** so try to replace

```
'Date:  ' . $_POST['$date'] . "\n" .
'IP:  ' . $_POST['$IP'] . "\n" .
'Host:  ' . $_POST['$Host'];
```

to

```
'Date:  ' . $date . "\n" .
'IP:  ' . $IP . "\n" .
'Host:  ' . $Host;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should attach like this(bellow) because $date, $IP and $Host are not transmitted in a post request:

```
$createdDate =  new DateTime();
$date= $createdDate->format('d.m.Y H:m');

$message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
           'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" .
           'Subject: ' . $_POST['subject'] . "\n" .
           'Department: ' . $_POST['department'] . "\n" .
           'Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . "\n" .
           'Date:  ' . $date. "\n" .
           'IP:  ' . $IP. "\n" .
           'Host:  ' . $Host;
```

Comment: Thank you, this way I can format my date as I wish!